# extract data from JSON api with python

Tags: python, arrays, json, api

hello fellows as you see on my code here i got the min price value
but the problem is i cant get the rest of the data linked with the minimum price such as
ingame_name and status especially status for the minimum price :

for example we take this item url :
https://api.warframe.market/v1/items/mirage_prime_systems/orders?include=item

as result we will get lot of open orders from that JSON Link , the thing i need to do here is to get min price of selling from an online player with all his basic info for the user .

here is my code

```
import requests
import json


item = input('put your item here please :  ')
gg = item.replace(' ', '_')
response_url =  requests.get(f'https://api.warframe.market/v1/items/'+ gg +'/orders?include=item')

data = json.loads(response_url.text)
orders = data["payload"]["orders"]
           
min_price = min(o["platinum"] for o in orders if o["order_type"] == "sell")


print(min_price)
```

and i seem i cant get do it unless u help me guys and i really appreciate it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use built-in `min()` with custom `key`. As you need to apply some filtering on initial data, there're two possible ways:

1. Filter data before searching minimum *(one of possible methods shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69423952/10824407) answer)*;
2. Exploit lexicographical comparison which is used in python to compare sequences *([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons))*.

I found second method is better as it makes possible to iterate over all orders just once *(which more efficient)*.

So to implement this we should return from `lambda` which we will pass to `min()` not just `"platinum"` key value, but also *boolean result of **inverted** conditions*.

Why inverted? Because we are searching for minimum value. It means that every return of our `lambda` will be compared with previous minimum. In python `False` equals 0 and `True` equals `1` *([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-10))*. `0 < 1` so if any of inverted conditions will be `True` all key will be greater ignoring `"platinum"` value.

**Code:**

```py
import requests
from json import JSONDecodeError

item = input("Put your item here please: ")

try:
    response = requests.get("https://api.warframe.market/v1/items/" +
                            item.lower().replace(" ", "_") + "/orders",
                            params={"include": "item"})
    json_data = response.json()
    orders = json_data["payload"]["orders"]
except requests.RequestException as e:
    print("An error occurred during processing request:", e)
except JSONDecodeError:
    print("Server response is not valid json:", response.text)
except KeyError as e:
    print("Response doesn't contain", e, "key")
except Exception as e:
    print("Unexpected error:", e)
else:
    min_price_order = min(orders, key=lambda x: (x["order_type"] != "sell",
                                                 x["user"]["status"] != "ingame",
                                                 x["platinum"]))
    print(min_price_order)
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter the list by order type and find the min using lambda

```
orders = [{'order_type':'sell','other':88,'platinum':4},
          {'order_type':'sell','other':77,'platinum':9},
          {'order_type':'buy','other':88,'platinum':4}]

min_price = min([o for o in orders if o["order_type"] == "sell"],key= lambda x : x ['platinum'])
print(min_price)
```

output

```
{'order_type': 'sell', 'other': 88, 'platinum': 4}
```

Comment: that works yep it does get the order of min sell price but if i try to extract for example status of player from min_price result
status = min_price['status']

gives error ?

Comment: share `orders` in the post and we will see what causes the error. BTW - What is the error?

Comment: `min_price['status']` --> `min_price['user']['status']` should work

Comment: `min(orders, key=lambda x: (x.get("order_type") != "sell", x["platinum"]))` could be an alternative to not create additional list

Comment: everything is great here using lambda solves everything the only problem is im trying to get the min from ingame players so ["status"] == "ingame" what do you think brother

Comment: @hracke, `min(data["payload"]["orders"], key=lambda x: (x["order_type"] != "sell", x["user"]["status"] != "ingame", x["platinum"]))`

Comment: @hracke, for this method my suggestion doesn't fit. You should patch list comprehension instead: `[o for o in orders if o["order_type"] == "sell" and x["user"]["status"] == "ingame"]`. Or you can omit list comprehension and pass unfiltered `orders` with key from previous comment.